# Wix Conditional WebApplicationExtension

Tags: wix, windows-installer, wix3.5

I'm trying to install an MVC website with my Wix installer. It should work for IIS 6 and IIS 7. If the target has IIS 6, I want to use

```
    <iis:WebApplicationExtension
    CheckPath="no"
    Executable="[NETFRAMEWORK40INSTALLROOTDIR]aspnet_isapi.dll"
    Verbs="GET,HEAD,POST"/>
```

If it's IIS 7+, I don't want to do this (since ASP .NET won't serve static content types by default).

How can I make the above line conditional? I know I can set a condition at the containing component...but that's not what I want, because the rest of the component (the Web Application itself) should be installed regardless...

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try to create two identical components, only with this setting different, and then set the condition on them.

Comment: Yea...I figured that was one possibility...but it seems kind of silly to repeat everything except that one part